# How to show progress bar for Selenium Script that is triggered by a button click of a PHP page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently executing a Selenium Script on a button click like this.

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
          <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Migrate to Cloud" id="upload" class="upload" onclick="upload()">
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function upload()
              {
                $.ajax
                ({
                  type:'post',
                  url:'db.php',
                  data:{
                    export_table:'export_table'
                  },
                  success:function(response) {
                    if(response=="success") {
                      alert("Table Exported");                        
                    }
                  }
                });             

                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "execute.php", true); 
                xmlhttp.send(); 
              } 
          </script>
        </div>
```

The script is running fine with minimized chrome browser window but in the front-end I want to show to the user a progress bar from the start till end with % whilst the automation script is executing.

Ps. the execute.php will have the java JAR file which consists of the recorded selenium script